# Scraper throws invalid url error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a scraper in python to get different lot numbers from a webpage. However, when I run my scraper, I see in the console that "the requested url is invalid". I tried to get the response url and found that it is the valid one. Is there anything I'm doing wrong in processing the request?
The script I'm trying with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload = {"keyword":"degas"}

headers={
"Content-Type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"
}

response = requests.get("http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?", params=payload, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
# tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
# for item in tree.cssselect("div.search-results-lot-number"):
#     print(item.text)

print(response.url)
print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
```

This is what I get in the console upon printing the "response.url", "response.text", and "response.status_code":

```
http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?keyword=degas
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#91;no&#32;URL&#93;", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;541d2017&#46;1503578560&#46;40be2bd
</BODY></HTML>

400
```

Btw, if I check the url manually then I find that it does lead me to that desired page.

Comment: The url you have is redirecting to a `not found` page. http://www.sothebys.com/en/notfound.html

Comment: Since you have `allow_redirects=False` in your request, it will just throw an error.

Comment: @ Mekicha, "allow_redirects=True" gives me the same results as I'm having with False parameter.

Comment: Remove `"Content-Type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8"` from headers

Comment: Oh my god! What a smart answer you gave sir Andersson. It works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working the below way.

```
import requests

payload = {
    'keyword':'degas',
    'pageSize':'24',
    'offset':'0'
    }

headers={
    'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Referer':'http://www.sothebys.com/en/search-results.html?keyword=degas',
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"
    }

response = requests.get("http://www.sothebys.com/en/search", params=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.url)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong headers. Following headers worked for me:

```
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="no-js pre-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="no-js ie7 pre-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="no-js ie8 pre-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>         <html xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html xml:lang="en" lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <!--GLOBAL META-->
<!-- requestUrl=/content/sothebys/en/search-results.html?keyword=degas -->
<title>Search Results | Sotheby's</title>
<meta name="description" content="View auction details, art exhibitions and online catalogues; bid, buy and collect contemporary, impressionist or modern art, old masters, jewellery, wine, watches, prints, rugs and books at sotheby's auction house">
<meta name="keywords" content="auction, art, exhibition, online, catalogue, bid, buy, collect, contemporary, impressionist, modern, old mast...
```

.
.
.

Comment: You are right Sam Chats, it did the magic for me as well. Sometimes, slim is not smart. I tried to make the User-Agent concise to give the parser a good appearance but it turns out to be faulty one. One last thing: If i take out the uncommented lines in my parser to get the lot number, why doesn't it fetch anything. Can you give me any idea on this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Shahin Try using "//div.search-results-lot-number".